# Ноутбук плохо ловит WIFI, в какую сторону смотреть?

Tags: windows, wifi, роутер, router, ноутбук

Ноутбуку год, но он очень плохо ловит wifi.
Роутер висит за дверью, но windows 10 показывает 3/4 палочек, из-за чего очень медленная скорость.

Адаптер - Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Wireless Network Adapter
Дрова и обновы последние.

Помню в Linux можно было повышать мощность wifi-адаптера, но на windows я ничего похожего не нашёл. Мне кажется дело в программной части.

Ноутбук разбирать не хочется, так как тот ещё на гарантии, и в сервисный центр я не могу его отнести, так как ежедневно работаю за ним.
В какую сторону смотреть и что можно попытаться сделать?

Comment: В первую очередь в сторону соседей. Вполне типичная ситуация, когда все дружно фонят своими роутерами и вайфай плохо работает вообще у всех

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atheros QCA9377 поддерживает 1 × 1 802.11a/b/g/n/ac

1 × 1 плохая комбинация антенн, очень чувствительна к помехам.

Ваш роутер поддерживает a/ac? если да, то попробуйте увеличить мощность 5 GHz на роутере. Если не поможет - попробуйте отключить 5 ГГц на ноутбуке в драйверах или на роутере. Сеть 2,4ГГц медленнее, но надежнее проходит через препядствия.

Возможно стоит сменить роутер.

Comment: На счёт помех. Вы точно подметили, ибо когда я включаю блютуз на том же ноутбуке, wifi начинает работать в несколько раз хуже. Не того я ожидал от ноутбука за 45к...

Роутер достаточно старый, 5ГГц не поддерживает. Поэтому в адаптере я в принципе отключил поддержу 5ГГЦ и 2,4ГГЦ.

Пожалуй и правда нужно задуматься над покупкой нового роутера.

Хотя что странно, Redmi note 8 pro очень хорошо ловил wifi, но новый Iphone 11 не ловит его практически также, как и ноутбук.